# SQL Query for Multiple Many to Many Relationships

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, many-to-many, inner-join

I need help with a query to get All Permissions for a User.

- A User can be be in 0-many Groups

  - Groups can have 0-many Users
- A Group can have 0-many Roles

  - A Role can be in 0-many Groups
- A Role can have 0-many Permissions

  - Permission can be on 0-many Roles

I have a User ID and I need to get all permissions for that User. So I need to get all the groups for a user ID, all the roles for each group for the user, and then all the permissions for the various roles.

I'm fine with the single many to many relationship query, but can seem to manage this nested query.

Example of my single many to many query:

```
SELECT        [Permission].*
FROM          [Permission] INNER JOIN
              Roles_Permissions ON Permission.PermissionID = Roles_Permissions.PermissionID INNER JOIN
              Role ON Roles_Permissions.RoleID = Role.RoleID
WHERE        (Role.RoleID = 5)
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? In this scenario you need one more entity, you created Groups_Roles ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the tables available and their structures follow the scheme suggested by permission-role_permissions-role, you can achieve what you want with a query like this:

```
SELECT  p.*
FROM    [Permission] p
JOIN    Roles_Permissions rp
ON      p.PermissionID = rp.PermissionID
JOIN    Group_Roles gr
ON      rp.RoleID = gr.RoleID
JOIN    User_Groups ug
ON      gr.GroupID = ug.GroupID
WHERE   ug.UserID = /*desired UserID*/
```

Actually you don't need to join the `User`, `Group` and `Role` tables, because all you need from those entities is the binding between their `ID`s, that are already available on the relationship tables.